# Why were so many PE files compiled in 2010?

Tags: datetime, compilation, timestamp, executable, portable-executable

I'm doing some PE file analysis using the pefile python package. I used pefile to extract TimeDateStamp from the header and find the compilation year.
Here is part of the code for extraction:

```
dates_list = []    
for program in path_list:

    pe = pefile.PE(program, fast_load=True)

    file_header_dict = pe.FILE_HEADER.dump_dict()
    string_date = file_header_dict["TimeDateStamp"]["Value"]

    parsed_date = string_date[string_date.find("[") + 1 : string_date.find("]")]
    date_object = datetime.datetime.strptime(parsed_date, "%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y %Z")

    dates_list.append(date_object.year)
```

This works fine, but produces some bizarre results. Here is the plot: [PE file by compilation date](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hODCK.png)

These are just regular windows .exes from my computer. Why are so many of them from 1970? Is there a reason for the spike at 2010?

Also not pictured are the .exes that claimed to be from the future (post 2021), I attributed them to Windows 10 weirdness but would also welcome comment on this issue.

pefile uses UTC so I do not think this is a localisation problem.

Answer (score 1):

As a matter of fact, time stamps (there are several in executable files) are not always meaningful and can be easily modified. Some compilers don't even put valid date within it.

[Why are the module timestamps in Windows 10 so nonsensical?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20180103-00/?p=97705)

Comment: cheers, then is there a better way to get an idea of .exe ages?